# Spring Security not working after migrating from version 3 to 4

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Recently I migrated from Spring Security 3 to version 4. Everything worked well before but now nothing works.

Here is my `spring-security.xml`:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/home.MRCMPU" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginFailure.MRCMPU" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*.MRCMPU"  access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/con" access="permitAll"/>

        <form-login 
            login-page="/home.MRCMPU"
            login-processing-url="/login"  authentication-success-handler-ref="AuthenticationSuccess" 
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="AuthenticationFailure" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout.MRCMPU" success-handler-ref="Logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="Authentication"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Can anyone find the conflict from this code?

Comment: Share the exception what you are getting

Comment: 404 error the form action url is not working

Comment: While starting the server itself you will get the exceptions,if configurations are not correct...as I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing many referrenced beans here.

1. `user-service-ref="Authentication"`
2. `success-handler-ref="Logout"`
3. `authentication-success-handler-ref="AuthenticationSuccess"`
4. `authentication-failure-handler-ref="AuthenticationFailure"`

For the above mentioned references,you should have beans otherwise,like

> No bean named 'Logout' is defined

Exception will be thrown.

Add bean class like

```
<bean id="Authentication"
     class="class which you need to refer">
 </bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

finally i cleared it myself.
by disabling csrf using xml

```
 <csrf disabled="true"/>
```

but how can i do it without disabling  csrf token